# Three.js, no shadow rendered (.stl files)

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm using three.js and I'm trying to make a good viewer for .stl files.
But I have a big problem with the shadow, for some files it's ok and for some other it's just horrible. (Most of the time, it's stl file that come from Blender that don't work).

Here are the two different render with a "normal" file and the same file import/export with Blender.
Images : http://imageup.fr/uploads/1367501292.jpeg & http://imageup.fr/uploads/1367501311.jpeg

Here is the code:

```
<script src="scripts/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="three/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="three/js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="three/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<div id='3d' style='width:400px;height:300px;margin:auto;position:relative;border:5px solid white;border-radius:5px;'>
    <script>

        var modele = document.getElementById('modele3d').value; 


      if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

      var container, stats;

      var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;


      init();
      animate();

      function init() {

        container = document.getElementById('3d');
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, 400 / 300, 0.1, 10000 );
        camera.position.set( 200, 200, 200 );
        cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x1875cd, 0, 100000 );



        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xaeadad, color: 0xfefcfc, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200} );
        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

          var geometry = event.content;
          var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

          mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
          mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );

          // Recherche et envoi des tailles //
          geometry.computeBoundingBox();
          var largeur = (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.x)-(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.x);
          var hauteur = (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y)-(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.y);
          var profondeur = (mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.z)-(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.z);
          var tailles = largeur + " " + hauteur + " " + profondeur;
          var prix  = document.getElementById('prototype_prix').value;
          if(prix==0){
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille1').value = Math.round(largeur);
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille2').value = Math.round(hauteur);
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille3').value = Math.round(profondeur);
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille1_base').value = largeur;  
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille2_base').value = hauteur;
          document.getElementById('prototype_taille3_base').value = profondeur; 
          }     

          geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
          var radius = mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
          mesh.position.set( 0, -radius/2, 0 );
          var d = 300/(2*radius);
          mesh.scale.set( d, d, d );

          mesh.castShadow = true;
          mesh.receiveShadow = true;
          scene.add( mesh );

        } );
        loader.load( 'images/'+modele);


        // Lights

        scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x777777 ) );

        addShadowedLight( 1, 1, 1, 0xffffff, 0.8 );
        addShadowedLight( 0.5, 1, -1, 0xfcd891, 0.6 );



        // renderer

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: false } );
        renderer.setSize( 400, 300);
        renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
        renderer.gammaInput = true;
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;
        renderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        // Trackball
                enhanced_control = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera,renderer.domElement);        
      }

      function addShadowedLight( x, y, z, color, intensity ) {

        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( color, intensity );
        directionalLight.position.set( x, y, z );
        scene.add( directionalLight );
        directionalLight.castShadow = true;
        directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
        directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 0;
        directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 20;
        directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
        directionalLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
        directionalLight.shadowBias = -0.005;
        directionalLight.shadowDarkness = 0.15;

      }

      function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = 400 / 300;
        renderer.setSize( 400, 300);
      }

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );       
        enhanced_control.update();
        render();
      }

      function render() {
        var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;          
        camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }




    </script>
    <p style='position:relative;margin-top:-310px;margin-left:3px;float:left;color:white;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #135da4'>Rendu 3D :</p>
    </div>
```

I hope you can help me, I have already passed a lot of time trying to make the render works :s

Comment: Your `mesh.scale` transformation indicates that your model will have a size of 150. But then you go and set the `shadowCameraFar` to 20. It is very small. Is your object inside the shadow camera cone? You have `shadowCameraVisible` so you should be able to see the cone.

Comment: Still not exactely the same render (one is lot more dark) but it works! Thank you for that, you made my day!

Comment: Just a note. The first image you posted does have shadows at all.

Comment: If the comment was helpfull, you could give some credit using the up-arrow on the left of the comment.